# Is it possible to configure system properties dynamically for a Gradle test task?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, gradle

Is it possible to configure system properties dynamically for a Gradle test task?  I haven't found a way to make it work.

I am working within my own Gradle plugin, `GwtPlugin`.  The `apply()` method looks like this:

```
/** Apply the plugin. */
void apply(Project project) {
   project.plugins.apply(JavaPlugin)
   project.plugins.apply(WarPlugin)

   project.extensions.create("gwt", GwtPluginExtension, project)
   project.extensions.create("testSuite", TestSuitePluginExtension, project)
   project.convention.plugins.gwt = new GwtPluginConvention(project)

   applyGwt(project)
   applyTestSuite(project)
}
```

In the `applyTestSuite()` method, I create a tasks for my test suites.  The definition for the `integrationtest` task looks like this:

```
// Run integration tests, assumed to be found in a class suites/IntegrationTestSuite.
project.task("integrationtest", type: org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test, dependsOn: project.tasks.buildApplication) {
    workingDir = { project.testSuite.getWorkingDir() == null ? project.projectDir : project.testSuite.getWorkingDir() }
    scanForTestClasses = false
    scanForTestClasses = false
    enableAssertions = false
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

    include "suites/IntegrationTestSuite.class"
    systemProperty "integration.test.server.wait", project.gwt.getServerWait()

    beforeSuite { descriptor ->
       if (descriptor.className == "suites.IntegrationTestSuite") {
          project.convention.plugins.gwt.rebootDevmode()
       }
    }

    afterSuite { descriptor ->
       if (descriptor.className == "suites.IntegrationTestSuite") {
          project.convention.plugins.gwt.killDevmode()
       }
    }
}
```

I want to get configuration for the `integration.test.server.wait` system property from `project.gwt.getServerWait()`.  I can't figure out how to make this work, and I'm beginning to think it's not possible.

If I hardcode the system property, everything works as expected:

```
systemProperty "integration.test.server.wait", 10
```

The problem seems to be that the system property is set when the task is defined, but my extension doesn't have any values at that point.  I can't figure out how to work around this.

For instance, I tried putting the `project.gwt.getServerWait()` call in a closure, but in that case the system property gets set to a string like:

```
com.me.gradle.GwtPlugin$_applyTestSuite_closure10_closure42@320de756
```

I also tried moving the `systemProperty` line to a `doFirst` block.  In that case, the `doFirst` block gets a sensible value from my extension (I can print it), but the assignment is apparently too late to influence the test runner.

Is there any way for me to accomplish this?  If not, is there another way to pass dynamic configuration to my test runner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to make this work.  The trick is to set the system property on the test task sometime later, when the property is certain to be available.  The simplest way to make that happen seems to be via a dummy dependency:

```
project.task("integrationtestconfig") << {
   outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
   project.tasks.integrationtest.systemProperty("integration.test.server.wait", project.gwt.getServerWait())
}

project.task("integrationtest", type: org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test, 
             dependsOn: project.tasks.buildApplication, project.tasks.integrationtestconfig)
...
```

It's not the elegant solution I was hoping for, but it does work and it's not too difficult to follow.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is:

```
ext {
    // Sets a sensible default
    myProperty project.properties.myProperty
}
task preTest << {
    // Computes the property...
    project.ext.myProperty = ...
}
task myTest {
    ...
    doFirst {
        systemProperty 'myProperty', project.ext.myProperty
    }
}
```

I define a sensible default value in the `gradle.properties` file:

```
myProperty = A sensible default value
```

In a multi module environment, it can be trickier. I then use `rootProject.ext.myProperty` from the `test` task.

Best regards,
Damien.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno what version you were using to do this, but this seems the most convenient way to me:

```
task doSomethingBeforeTest {
    doLast {
      // some stuff to do
        test {
            systemProperties['some.property'] = 'prop'
        }
    }
}
```

basically, just put that `test` block in your task and set the property. (this works as of gradle 4.0 - not sure about previous versions, but I imagine it would).

Comment: This question is from 2013, and I was using Gradle 2.5 at the time.   This sort of construct did not appear to work with 2.5, but it's good to see that's changed in 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this works, but have you tried to do it in this way

```
doLast {
    systemProperty "integration.test.server.wait", project.gwt.getServerWait()
}
```

within your plugin script?

May be this has to do with the phase (configuration, ... ) when the things are resolved in gradle.

Comment: I had tried it with `<<` rather than an explicit `doLast` block, which didn't work.  I just re-tested to confirm.  The `doLast` is executed after the suite is finished running.

Comment: To clarify, I added the `doLast` block to the definition for the `integrationtest` task within my plugin script.